# Position Fixed and Backface Visibility

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have three sectioning areas and within these I have a header element and a child item that is position fixed.

As the user scrolls I want the next section to go over the previous section including its fixed child.

I have this working in Chrome by using backface visibility:

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;    
-moz-backface-visibility: hidden;   
-ms-backface-visibility: hidden;    
backface-visibility: hidden;
```

But in FF, the fixed items are no longer fixed. Take a look at the my jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7KjXm/5/

Is this expected behaviour? Is there a cross browser solution? Or is JS the way to go?

Thanks....

Comment: Do you need to have actual HTML content with a fixed position? Or would a background-image suffice?

Comment: [It's a bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=876341), I think you'll have to work around it

Comment: What does backface-visibility has to do with what you want to achieve here?

Comment: @az101 Chrome (Webkit) behaves wrong in this case. The `backface-visibility` property should have no effect in this case, as there is no CSS 3D Transform. I guess I know what you are trying to achieve, but this is not possible with CSS for now, as there is no way to change styles depending on the screen position of an element. There is a new value for the position property called "[sticky](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Sticky_positioning)" but for now only supported in Safari 6.1+. So let us know if you prefer a JS or a CSS solution?

Comment: Thanks all; so the spec says "The ‘backface-visibility’ property determines whether or not the "back" side of a transformed element is visible when facing the viewer." - that's obviously working in both browsers. The fact that Firefox removes any fixed positioning is a bug but also the way that Chrome is handling these fixed elements isn't correct either(?).. In that they should always be fixed relative to the viewport - no new stacking order should be applied to the containing element that has 'backface-visibility'. Is that correct?

Answer (score 7):

I managed to solve the effect you were looking for. Unfortunately, it does not seem possible to do with only css ([yet](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/08/Stick-your-landings-position-sticky-lands-in-WebKit)).

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/8F2Zc/3/) is my solution that uses jquery and modified css of the original page. I switched to numbers instead of colored elements and changed the sizes.

My javascript for fake floating elements (allows for them to be hidden when the view moves away):

```
$(function(){
    elem = $('.fixeditem');
    win  = $(window);
    wrap = $('<div>').css({
        width: elem.width(),
        height: elem.height()
    });
    elem.wrap(wrap);
    win.scroll(function() {
        elem.each(function(index, element){
            element = $(element);
            var offset = element.parent().offset().top;
            element.css('top', win.scrollTop() + 40 - offset);
        });
    });
});
```

My custom css for this specific example:

```
html, body{
    height: 100%;
}

.item {
    min-height:100%;
    background-color: white;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.header {
    position: relative;
    background-color: green;
    padding: 5px;
    z-index: 2;
}

.fixeditem {
    position: relative;
    top: 10%;
    left: 50%;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

Colored update of code: http://jsfiddle.net/8F2Zc/4/

Hope this helps!

Comment: If you want to change the distance the object is away from the top then change the `40` in the css function to whatever value you like. To add percent values, you will need to also retrieve the window size.

Comment: Thanks Tyler! This is pretty similar to my final JS solution. Calculating the top position of each fixed element as the user scrolls.

Comment: You are very welcome. The only issue I have found with this, is that it seems ugly on my tablet (I was using chrome). Hope that still works for you.